# Getting Latitude and Longitude using GPS Averaging app on android phone?

Tags: gps, android

I am trying to get latitude and longitude of radio stations across my country (Liberia) using an Android phone. I downloaded GPS Averaging but I keep getting an error which says:

> NO GPS SIGNAL

How can I use an Android phone to get Lat/long?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains our "no chit-chat" policy. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a GIS component to this question -- interacting with the GPS device within a phone is actually more of a software engineering challenge, especially if the hardware if faulty.  It's likely possible to obtain the coordinates of transmission towers through other means, so it's possible your intended solution is unnecessary.